# How to update an EditText to convert input into currency? (Android Newbie)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext, currency

I have a number of EditText's with an inputType="numberDecimal" and i'm wanting to change the input into currency (TextWatcher maybe?). Can anyone help with this? 99% of my project is done bar this. Thanks guys.

Comment: change the input into currency? what are you expecting the user to input?

Comment: Add another TextView directly to the left of the decimal EditText, and put in a "$".

Comment: can you show us what you want as a output?

Comment: [link](i.imgur.com/1e8lpG8.png) When the user inputs it looks like the add charges but I want it to look like the total in the run box after the user is finished typing or does it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code:-

```
    tv.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {
        private String current = "";
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
        {
            if(!s.toString().equals(current))
            {
                if(tv.getText().toString().trim().length()>0)
                {
                    tv.removeTextChangedListener(this);
                    String formated = tv.getText().toString().trim().replace("$", "");
                    current = formated;
                    tv.setText("$"+formated);
                    tv.setSelection(formated.length()+1);   

                    tv.addTextChangedListener(this);
                }
            }
        }

         @Override
         public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
         {
         }
         @Override
         public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s)
         { 
         }
    });
```

Comment: The code works great! What about if I wanted to use the .getCurrencyInstance? Thank you so much you have no idea how long this has annoyed me.